# Authenticating against multiple flaky Membership providers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

Currently my asp.net app has 5 ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and 1 SqlMembershipProvider.  Both of those numbers are bound to increase at least some in the near future.  The problem is that some of the domains we are authenticating against are flaky.  So one out of the 5 might be unreachable for 30 min on Sunday for example.  When a user from any provider tries to login during that time they can't do it because the Providers collection throws an error.  So if one is down, they are all down.  Not fun.

I have tried about 72 different ways to approach this and haven't had any luck.  Here are my top 3.

1: add them all in web.config, override login control authenticate and loop through all Membership.Providers.  ValidateUser until we have a match.  Works great unless the above mentioned issue.  If one is down, the collection poops out and no one gets in.

B.  Only authenticate against default provider.  Have user pick which provider to use and change that to default provider using WebConfigurationManager.  Pretty great except for that you are actually changing the web.config file at runtime...  Oops!  Did I do that?

III.  Custom provider that checks domain user wants to login with, and in the Initiate() supply appropriate config values from source other than web.config.  DB table with all the separate providers info.  Then we always ValidateUser on the custom provider, who then checks user picked domain/provider, plugs info in and off we go.  This works except if I logout and then login with a diff domain...  I can't do that because it's already initialized to the other domain you picked before.

Maybe I am missing something easy?  I hope so.  StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: "If I authenticated against any provider - I'm in" - is it true in your case?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can authenticate to one of the providers, we let you in.  The app controls what you see from there.